# How can I identify if the executed ghostscript command returned an error in Perl?

Tags: perl, ghostscript

I am having problem to get ghostscript's error return code to know if it failed or not,
I tried corrupting a PostScript file (messed it up on a file editor) and ran it, but I could not get a 1 or non-0 return.
After reading some manual and topics about it(hardly) here, this is what I currently do:

```
my $cmd = "/apps/gs/ghostpdl-9.52/bin/gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ps2write -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=$output -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -f $psfile";
logmsg("command: $cmd");
my $rc = `$cmd`;
logmsg("rc: $rc");
if($rc != 0){
    ...
}
```

but $rc doesn't have any value so I couldn't satisfy $rc != 0
Hopefully someone could help.

Thanks

Comment: Use `system` instead? Backticks return what the command prints to standard output, not exit codes.

Comment: The exit code is in `$?`, cf [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#%60STRING%60).

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, I tried it, it returned 0 instead of nothing, but still it is returning 0 for that corrupted file...

Comment: Better use modules to manage external commands. For one, they provide much better reporting of error and response from the command.  Some: `IPC::System::Simple`, `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run`

Comment: Are you sure it is returning non-zero when run directly in shell?

Comment: Does gs actually error out on the file if you run it directly? On Unix systems, gs generally has a "non-zero" exit code, in the event of exiting with a PS error. And it *is* Postscript file, *not* a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

If the command outputs an error message to STDERR (and many do), then you need to append  `2>&1` to the command  in order to redirect STDERR to STDOUT for capture by the backticks, like so:

```
my $output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
```

Then check `$output` for some kind of error or success message. I suggest printing it in order to see to see what it contains.

Note that the return value of backticks is the output of the command, not it's return status! If you really want the native return status of the  command executed by the backticks, you can get that information using `$?` or `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`. See `perldoc perlvar` for details.